# C Programming under Windows

Tags: c

I was reading a program in Programming Windows by Charles Petzold. I was stuck at one point. There was a Line :

```
cxCaps=(tm.tmPitchAndFamily & 1?3:2)*cxChar/2;
```

where `cxCaps` (a static variable) saves an average width of uppercase letters

My Question is what is `& 1 ? 3 : 2` ?

I know it is conditional operator but what is 1 2 3.

Could anyone explain the whole `cxCaps` line?

Comment: The 1 is the right operand of the &, so you could read it as `cxCaps=( (tm.tmPitchAndFamily & 1)  ?3:2)*cxChar/2;`

Comment: Your question is actually "what is **tm.tmPitchAndFamily & 1 ? 3 : 2** " which ... should explain it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a series of operations. Lets put it in parentheses:

```
((tm.tmPitchAndFamily & 1) ? 3 : 2) * (cxChar / 2);
```

So first the `tm.tmPitchAndFamily & 1` operation is performed, which check if `tm.tmPitchAndFamily` is odd (if the least significan bit is set, then it's odd). The result of this operation is then part of the [ternary expression `?:`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#C). If the left hand side of the ternary expression is non-zero (i.e. true), then the left hand side of the `:` is selected, otherwise the right hand side. Then the result of that (which is `3` or `2`) is used in the multiplication.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for answering the question

Answer (score 2):

```
cxCaps=(tm.tmPitchAndFamily & 1?3:2)*cxChar/2;
```

and

```
if (tm.tmPitchAndFamily & 1) {
  cxCaps=3*cxChar/2;
} else {
  cxCaps=2*cxChar/2;
}
```

are the same

On the other hand, `&` is bitwise operator `AND`

In this case means:

if bit `1` is set in `tm.tmPitchAndFamily`

> Bitwise AND The bitwise AND operator is a single ampersand: &. A handy
>   mnemonic is that the small version of the boolean AND, &&, works on
>   smaller pieces (bits instead of bytes, chars, integers, etc). In
>   essence, a binary AND simply takes the logical AND of the bits in each
>   position of a number in binary form.
>
> For instance, working with a byte (the char type):
>
> 01001000 &  10111000 = 
>   -------- 00001000
>
> The most significant bit of the first number is 0, so we know the most
>   significant bit of the result must be 0; in the second most
>   significant bit, the bit of second number is zero, so we have the same
>   result. The only time where both bits are 1, which is the only time
>   the result will be 1, is the fifth bit from the left. Consequently,
>
> 72 & 184 = 8

Comment: The OP said he knows what the conditional operator is. His problem is that he doesn't see/understand the bitwise operation

Answer (score 2):

the `a ? b : c` construct is a if expression, which means : "if a is true, then the value is b else the value is c", for example:

```
int foo = 0 ? 1 : 2;
```

foo will be 2

```
int foo = 1 ? 2 : 3;
```

foo will be 1.

The `&` operator is a bitwise operator that will apply a mask on the value.

If you look at [the operator precedence in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence), the `:?` ternary if has lower precedence than the bitwise if. It will check whether last bit of `tm.tmPitchAndFamily` is true, and thus whether its value is odd. And that value will be used in the multiplication.

In the end, I'd say that the way the expression is written is confusing and would have been better if written as follows:

```
cxCaps=(tm.tmPitchAndFamily&1 ? 3 : 2)*cxChar/2;
```

Finally, to answer your first question:

> My Question is what is & 1 ? 3 : 2 ?
>   I know it is conditional operator but what is 1 2 3.

- `1` is being used as a test to know if the left hand value is odd or not
- if that value is odd, `3` is being used in the rest of the operation
- otherwise `2` is being used there.

Only the context of that statement can tell you why the writer made those design choices.